# How to send gmail emails in python while including default email signature and font size?

Tags: python, gmail

I am trying to send emails via Gmail using Python. However I would like to add my email signature and font size (large size) that is already specified in my Gmail settings. Below is code to send the email; what do I need to add to accomplish this requirement?

Code as follows:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

subject = "Offer"
message = "My offer is 2 dollars"


email = "sender@gmail.com"  
password ='mypassword'
send_to_email = "recipient@gmail.com"  

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = email
msg["To"] = send_to_email
msg["Subject"] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain text MIME parts (`text/plain`) do not have a font size; they are just ASCII text without any formatting facilities (beyond what ASCII provides, i.e. line breaks and perhaps tabs).

If you want to embed formatting, send HTML email.

Incidentally, your code looks like it's pre-Python 3.6; the `email` library went through a significant overhaul in that version. New code should generally target the new `EmailMessage` API, which is more straightforward and also more versatile than the old one, which required you to explitly set up a MIME structure in every message. See [the examples in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for good starting points.

Comment: ... Though personally, I prefer plain text, and am offended by email which tries to override my font preferences.